# How to Embedding Cordova WebView on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

First,I create an xcode project ,then I add the Cordova to the project

I made this step by step with this tutorial： http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

but still got the error

```
Libtool /Users/wanyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCordova-bmqmtqdeafhklhbjqbnmochohdoe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a normal i386
    cd /Users/wanyc/Downloads/infoviz-ios-master/CordovaLib
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/wanyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCordova-bmqmtqdeafhklhbjqbnmochohdoe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/wanyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCordova-bmqmtqdeafhklhbjqbnmochohdoe/Build/Intermediates/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Cordova.LinkFileList -all_load -Obj-C -lsqlite3.0 -o /Users/wanyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCordova-bmqmtqdeafhklhbjqbnmochohdoe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `O' in: -Obj-C
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

I find the error cased by this `'Add -all_load and -Obj-C - for the "Other Linker Flags" value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `-ObjC`, not `-Obj-C`. [Here's an example in Apple's documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

(Also, please don't show screenshots of compiler errors -- they get resized so small that they're nearly unreadable. You can copy and paste the text out of the error log.)